# nodelist index access does not return the node, but instead 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, nodelist

given an application that can produce a webpage that has multiple and varying instances of the following html element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="jpd-model" id="jpd-model-1" value="XXXX-900L-XXXX~(120,277)">
```

i have the following javascript code:

```
const modelInputs = document.getElementsByName('jpd-model')
console.log(modelInputs)
```

it returns correctly a NodeList of all the elements that match correctly.

however the code below is an attempt access an item in the NodeList above:

```
const modelInputs = document.getElementsByName('jpd-model')
console.log(modelInputs[0])
```

but instead returns `undefined`

i would expect the first node of modelInputs

Is undefined expected here, and if not what could be causing that?

using latest brave browser on linux

*this is a redo of a question i asked previously that got closed, i'm hoping i fix correctly here.*

this was closed because it was assumed another question answered this, it does not, the difference here is that if that was the case then the first code example i have would not work either, but it does.

Comment: Sounds like the script is running before the element exists in the DOM

Comment: Can you add the output of the working `console.log(modelInputs)`